# How to search Query Store for a specific word or command in a query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, shrink, query-store, string-searching

I have an Enterprise Edition of SQL 2016 SP1, that has a database with Query Store active.

I want to search for a specific word or command in the saved queries. I have googled around and not seen anything. In this case I want to find 'SHRINK', but the same approach should be usable for any text in stored query.

Anticipating the "why?" comment. I have a vendor app that does a bunch of work and then shrinks the database and log files. I am trying to find the query that does it.

How to search Query Store for a specific word or command in a query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [sp_BlitzErik](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/32281/sp-blitzerik) mentioned in a comment, and as I gathered from my own research, you can find some things in [`sys.query_store_query_text`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-query-store-query-text-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) but not necessarily always a `SHRINK`.

This query returns 22,497 results:

```
SELECT  qsqt.*
FROM    sys.query_store_query_text AS qsqt
WHERE qsqt.query_sql_text LIKE '%Select%'
```

This query does not return any, except the second time I run it :)

```
SELECT  qsqt.*
FROM    sys.query_store_query_text AS qsqt
WHERE qsqt.query_sql_text LIKE '%SHRINK%'
```

The foundation of the query above comes from a [SQL with Bert post](https://bertwagner.com/2017/11/14/how-to-search-stored-procedures-and-ad-hoc-queries/).

A coworker has shown me a query that finds the shrink and the time and login of who did it.  So I have what I need for the my specific issue, but that is something of a side step from my question.

My workaround uses the default query trace. It shows multiple recent `DBCC Shrinkdatabase ('MyDB', TRUNCATEONLY)` that are run against the *master* database, which does not have query store.

A `DBCC SHRINKFILE` run in the context of a database with query store enabled does get recorded in the query store.